# Черный экран эмулятора

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Использую эмулятор в Android Studio в отдельном окно (в настройках студии выставлено `Launch  in a tool window`)
Сегодня запускаю проект - на эмуляторе черный экран.
По логам вижу, что прилага работает.
Запускаю Layout-инспектор - он все показывает.
Двигаю по черному экрану там, где должны быть элементы - все работает, переходит на другие экраны.

Вернул эмулятор в окно студии - все стало работать. Но меня это не устраивает.

В чем может быть проблема? Как фиксить? Вчера вечером все работало, сегодня чет сломалось.